# One getter returns null, the others return the acctual value firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a pretty strange problem with my firebase database, or with a class, where just one of the getters doesn't work as the headline implies.

This is from the "CustomProtocolOther" class:

```
public class CustomProtocolOther implements Parcelable {
    public String pileID;
    public String dimHead;


    public CustomProtocolOther() {
    }
 public CustomProtocolOther(String pileID,
                            String dimHead,


    ) {

        this.pileID = pileID;
        this.dimHead = dimHead;

    }

    protected CustomProtocolOther(Parcel in) {

        pileID = in.readString();
        dimHead = in.readString();


    }

    public static final Creator<CustomProtocolOther> CREATOR = new Creator<CustomProtocolOther>() {
        @Override
        public CustomProtocolOther createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new CustomProtocolOther(in);
        }

        @Override
        public CustomProtocolOther[] newArray(int size) {
            return new CustomProtocolOther[size];
        }
    };

    public void setPileID(String pileID) {
        this.pileID = pileID;
    }

    public String getPileID() {
        return pileID;
    }

    public void setDimHead(String dimHead) {
        this.dimHead = dimHead;
    }

    public String getDimHead() {
        return dimHead;
    }
  @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(pileID);
        parcel.writeString(dimHead);

    }
}
```

In another activty I'm trying to get both dimHead and pileID like this:

```
private void populateOtherTextViews() {
        mProtocolDatabaseReferenceOther = mProtocolDatabaseReference.child(pileID).child(other); // 7901337/1/_other

        mProtocolDatabaseReferenceOther.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String s = protocolOther.getPileID();

                String p = protocolOther.getDimHead();
               }
}
```

But the latter one only returns null, I cant seem to figure out why getDimHead doesnt work? What have i missed?

When I run the program I debug it finds that there are a value in dimHead's node, but the getter just returns null. 
Attached is a snippet of the firebase database.

UPDATE: The protocolOther get instantiated in onCreate from intent:

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
        EXISTING_PROTOCOL = intent.getBooleanExtra("ExitingProtocol", false);
        protocolOther = intent.getParcelableExtra("protocolOthers");
        protocolAmount = intent.getParcelableExtra("protocolAmounts");
```

[image: Firebase data]

Comment: In `onDataChange(`), where is the statement that initializes `protocolOther`?  Do you use `protocolOther = dataSnapshot.getValue(CustomProtocolOther.class)`?

Comment: I have updated the question. I initializes protocolOther from the intent. 
But i have found a solution by using addValueEventListener and onDataChange. But it is so weird that i cant put everything in the Intent.

Comment: @Rasmus have you read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=en)? To get the value from the `DataSnapshot`, you need to do `protocolOther = dataSnapshot.getValue(CustomProtocolOther.class)` inside the `onDataChange` method

Comment: Thank you for your answer :
I have a list with a lot of protocols, and i would like to get the entire protocol via intent if a listitem gets clicked on, so it isnt possible to send everything via Intent?